# convert Array to object Angularjs

Tags: arrays, angularjs, object, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model

I have an array like `var names=["price","quality","service"]`, I have to convert that array to object like `names=[{"name":"price", "value":"1.3"},{"name":"quality","value":"3"},{"name":"service","value":"3.4"}]`. Each and every time array values are different. I need to do build the input field with that values by using `ng-repeat` like

```
<div ng-repeat="n in names">
      <input name="rating" ng-model="n" value="0"/>
</div>
```

How I can fetch the values as objects when user submits the form. can any one help me.

**Update**

I need json as like this:::

`names=[{"name":"price", "value":"1.3"},{"name":"quality","value":"3"},{"name":"service","value":"3.4"}]`

ThanQ!

Comment: where are the values coming from??

Comment: values are comming from database

Answer (score 1):

Declare you model object

`$scope.item={};`

Then just do

```
<div ng-repeat="n in names">
      <input name="rating" ng-model="item[n]" value="0"/>
</div>
```

The data will be collected into `item` object.

**Update**: To get such in such a model, we would have to create it before binding it to view. Assuming `names` has all the items in the controller do:

`var items=names.map(function(name){ return { name:name,value:null}; })`

This creates an array of the format you require.

Now bind the view to:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
          <input name="rating" ng-model="item.value" value="0"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi @Chandermani, I have updated the question. Could you Please help to solve that one